# Zapier Catch (Raw) Hook JSON parsing issue

Tags: json, zapier

I would like to configure sync between two different CRMs (Clevertap and Intercom) using Zapier and Webhooks. In general Clevertap sends the following JSON to webhook:

```json
{
    "targetId": 1548328164, 
    "profiles": [
        {
            "event_properties": {
                "MSG-sms": true, 
                "MSG-push": true, 
                "businessRole": "EMPLOYEE", 
                "Mobile Number": "123123123123", 
                "Name": "Artem Hovtvianisa", 
                "Title": "Mr", 
                "Last Name": "Hovtvianisa", 
                "Gender": "M", 
                "Customer type": "Business Account Holder", 
                "MSG-email": true, 
                "First Name": "Artem", 
                "Last seen IP": "111.177.74.50", 
                "tz": "GMT+0200", 
                "International customer": "yes", 
                "isBusiness": true, 
                "Email": "xxxyyy@gmail.com", 
                "Identity": 15675
            }, 
            "objectId": "e32e4de3c1e84b2d9bab3707c92cd092", 
            "all_identities": [
                "15675", 
                "xxxyyy@gmail.com"
            ], 
            "email": "xxxyyy@gmail.com", 
            "identity": "15675"
        }
    ]
}
```

Zapier provides two types of catch webhook: regular and Raw.

**Catch Raw Hook**

When I use this type, JSON raw data will be handled OK and on the next step (Zapier JS code app) I am able to pass proper JSON data like in example above.

[image]

However when I use simple JS code to parse JSON object and get profiles[0] array value I get the following error "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

**JS Code from Code step**:

```
var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(inputData));
console.log(result.profiles[0]);
return result;
```

[image]

**Catch Hook**

In case I use regular Catch Hook, hook parse data in some odd way, like this:

[image]

JSON.parse cannot recognize this structure.

Please advise how can I handle Webhook Zapier step in a proper way in order to get profiles[0] array item values?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. You're on the right track!

Catch Raw Hook is the way to go here. Your issue is that the data is coming in as a string and you're re-stringifying it before parsing it, which gets you back to where you came from. A simpler version:

```js
JSON.stringify("asdf") // => "\"asdf\"", quotes in the string
JSON.parse("\"asdf\"") // => "asdf", the original string
"asdf".profiles // => undefined
undefined[0] // => error, cannot read property "0" of undefined
```

Instead, just parse it and you're good to go!

```js
// all your variables are already in "inputData", so yours, 
// also named inputData, must be referenced explicitly. 
const result = JSON.parse(inputData.inputData); 
return {result: result, firstProfile: result.profiles[0]};
```

Comment: Hello David, Unfortunately your suggestion doesn't work either, please see screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/Un0HAIk.png Please advise how to proceed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Govtart you're calling `JSON.parse(inputData)`, where `inputData` is the whole input object Zapier supplies. You need to reference the sub variable (which you have also named `inputData`): `JSON.parse(inputData.inputData);`